# What cool things can I do with GPX routes that I have collected from my travels?

Tags: gps-navigation

Whilst I was cycle touring and walking around in a bunch of different cities, I tracked many of my routes. I wondered if anyone had suggestions of cool things to do with GPX routes?

Comment: Sorry, this question doesn't seem quite on-topic for Travel-SE. Perhaps Bicycles-SE could be a better fit? At any rate, asking for suggestions and recommendations is off-topic on SE sites in general, see the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: As @mindcorrosive said this is off-topic because of of the question form, I'm going to close this. However, I would consider to go to hikr.org with your data.